# Cannot create bean with the name RequestMappingHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to learn Spring with Hibernate. I am using Java 17.0.4; Hibernate 5.3.26; and Spring 5.0.2. I am taking Chad Darby's Udemy Course "Spring and Hibernate for Beginners (includes Spring Boot). I am having the following problem:

My stack trace:

```
Aug 29, 2022 2:47:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: web-customer-tracker
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@458ad742
```

My controller:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {
        
        return "list-customers";
    }
    
}
```

My JSP (list-customers.jsp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>List Customers</title>
    
</head>

<body>

List Customers - coming soon ...

</body>

</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Spring 5.0 doesn't support Java17, either switch to Spring 5.3 or use java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by the later part `Failed to introspect class ...`.
This is usually caused by a missing dependency.

Including the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or something like this in your Gradle config (not sure if the syntax is correct, haven't been using Gradle for a very long time):

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

Should solve your issue.
Otherwise, please provide your project configuration (pom or Gradle config) and StackTrace, if available.